# How can I pass a char array to another char array when using strlen()?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char array1[20]="hello world";
    char array2[20];
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(array1);i++)
        array2[i]=array1[i];
    array2[i]=NULL;
    cout<<array2<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: error]

How can I fix this error?

> error: i is undeclared identifier

On  `array2[i]=NULL;`

Comment: Read about scope. And don't write code like this - use std::string.

Comment: I copied this  from a website and it was working there , when i tried it ,it didn't work

Comment: Avoid that website.

Answer (score 0):

`int i` declared inside the `for` loop scope, so you can't use it outside the loop (before or after). You can declare it above the loop to use it after and inside the loop:

```
int main() {
    char array1[20] = "hello world";
    char array2[20];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(array1); i++)
        array2[i] = array1[i];
    array2[i] = NULL;
    std::cout << array2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The next example may help you understand the scope idea:

```
using namespace std;
int main() { // Main Scope

    cout << j << endl; // Error - j is not declared yet
    cout << i << endl; // Error - i is not declared yet
    int i = 3; // i is now belong to the main scope.

    { // First Inner Scope
        int j = 4; // j is now belong to the first inner scope.

        {  // Second Inner Scope
            string str = "aaa"; // str is now belong to the second inner scope.
            cout << j << endl; // Work
            cout << i << endl; // Work
            cout << str << endl; // Work
        }

        cout << j << endl; // Work
        cout << i << endl; // Work
        cout << str << endl; // Error - str is not belong to this scope
    }

    cout << i << endl; // Work
    cout << j << endl; // Error - j is not belong to this scope
    cout << str << endl; // Error - str is not belong to this scope
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much , it worked^^ , but i have  a question , ( array2[i]=NULL) statement is the result of for loop if the condition is false,isn't it?

Comment: if the condition is false in the `for` loop, the loop part is over. The parts that after the loop are not belong to the loop. But one of the statements of coding says that each line influenced by the previous ones.